# Filter djnago model using dynamic value as its field name

Tags: postgresql, django-models, filter

I want to filter my django model with a dynamic value as it's field or column name.

For example..

```
#were grade is a field in table Employee

assuming_field = grade  

instance = Employee.objects.get(assuming_field=5)
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what problem you've come across and therefore what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this

```
kwargs = {'id__in': [1, 2, 3, 4]}  #example
or 
kwargs = {'grade': <something>}
instance = Employee.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

**Note: Here lookup is a dynamic string, you can use a valid dynamic lookup.**